# Is there any keras code to reproduce the weight pruning of MobileNet?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pruning, mobilenet

I want to prune the MobileNetV1 model using the weight pruning method from https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning
However, I don't know how to set the `pruning_schedule`.

```py
pruning_params = {
      'pruning_schedule': sparsity.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.50,
                                                   final_sparsity=0.90,
                                                   begin_step=2000,
                                                   end_step=end_step,
                                                   frequency=100)
}
```

This is the code from the mnist example. If I want the final_sparsity to be 0.75 and fine tune from the keras MobileNet, how should I set the `initial_sparsity`, `begin_step`, `end_step` and `frequency`? Or should I use `ConstantSparsity` instead of `PolynomialDecay`?